# Query not executing

Tags: php, postgresql

I am new to postgresql and i don't know what is the syntax error in my query.What happens is when i execute the following query..it shows syntax error in pgadmin..

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement(implementor, scheme_code, phycomp_code, month_code, finmonthcode, year_code, target_ach, updated_by, remarks, ason, reason_code)
VALUES (0,'$schemecode', $phycompcode, $entrymonth, $finmonthcode, $finyearcode, $targetach, '$empcode', '$remarksave', '$as_onsave', $reason_codesave)";
```

when i am echoing the query..it appears as..

```
INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement( implementor, scheme_code, phycomp_code, month_code, finmonthcode, year_code, target_ach, updated_by, remarks, ason, reason_code) 
VALUES (0, 'AGR3-17', 3, 6, 6, 2017, 0, '13', '', '2017-07-12', )
```

If i insert reason code it executes successfully..but when the reason code is null..the error occurs..help me solving this..please..

Comment: You need to set the reason code to postgresql NULL, not php null. Using a prepared statement with bind variables will help you with this

Comment: @rypskar-it is not set as not null in pgadmin..bro

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php

Comment: You shouldn't use string concatenation or variable substitution for building SQL queries.  One reason is the issue you're having here when one or more of the variables are null you'll end up with an invalid query.  Another is that concatenation/variable substitution leave your application open to SQL injection attacks.  You're strongly advised to use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use prepared statements. They will handle you this kind of edge cases.

First, read the manual of [pg_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php).

Your code will look like this:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement(implementor, scheme_code, phycomp_code, month_code, finmonthcode, year_code, target_ach, updated_by, remarks, ason, reason_code)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = pg_prepare($connection, $sql1);
$values = array(0,$schemecode, $phycompcode, $entrymonth, $finmonthcode, $finyearcode, $targetach, $empcode, $remarksave, $as_onsave, $reason_codesave);
$result = pg_execute($connection, $stmt, $values);
```

Note that you don't have to deal with string or numeric presentation of your values.

Further reading:

- [PDO.prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- [odbc_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php)

You can use [pg_query_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) if you don't want to reuse the sql statement, as Craig Ringer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 11 fields and only 10 values.

Ah, look, `$reason_codesave` is not in single quotes. That's why it's missing from the echo.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement(implementor, scheme_code,phycomp_code, month_code, finmonthcode,year_code, target_ach,updated_by,remarks,ason,reason_code)
VALUES (0,'$schemecode',$phycompcode,$entrymonth,$finmonthcode,$finyearcode,$targetach,                                     '$empcode','$remarksave','$as_onsave','$reason_codesave')";
```

Comment: no brother,,i have all the 11 fields..the last field is reason code which i have entered null

Comment: Yes but it does not return as 'NULL' to the executing statement. you need to wrap in single quotes to return an empty string, your current method is not working.

Comment: how can you see that and not suggest pg_query_params ?

Comment: when i wrapping it with single qoutes it gives the error ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: " "

Comment: I think the problem in your query is that reason code is of datatype int and you are trying to select an empty string ('').

You have to workaround:

Change reason code to varchar ( reason code eg. 10 will be consider as strings I dont know if it is ok for your project) . Just give it a try by manually changing data type to varchar and re-execute the query once.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$reason_codesave` value before insertion into DB if it is null then pass an empty string.
Try like this

```
$reason_codesave=($reason_codesave)?$reason_codesave:' ';
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement(implementor, scheme_code,phycomp_code, month_code,
          finmonthcode,year_code, target_ach,updated_by,remarks,ason,reason_code)
          VALUES (0,'$schemecode',$phycompcode,$entrymonth,$finmonthcode,$finyearcode,$targetach,
         '$empcode','$remarksave','$as_onsave','$reason_codesave')";
```

**Or else you can do this**

```
if($reason_codesave){
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement(implementor, scheme_code,phycomp_code, month_code,
          finmonthcode,year_code, target_ach,updated_by,remarks,ason,reason_code)
          VALUES (0,'$schemecode',$phycompcode,$entrymonth,$finmonthcode,$finyearcode,$targetach,
         '$empcode','$remarksave','$as_onsave','$reason_codesave')";
}else{
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement(implementor, scheme_code,phycomp_code, month_code,
              finmonthcode,year_code, target_ach,updated_by,remarks,ason)
              VALUES (0,'$schemecode',$phycompcode,$entrymonth,$finmonthcode,$finyearcode,$targetach,
             '$empcode','$remarksave','$as_onsave')";
}
```

It will work for you.

Comment: do you use this `'$empcode','$remarksave','$as_onsave','$reason_codesave')";`  in your quey.It will echo like
`INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement( implementor, scheme_code,phycomp_code, month_code, finmonthcode,year_code, target_ach, updated_by,remarks,ason,reason_code) VALUES (0, 'AGR3-17',3,6,6,2017,0, '13','','2017-07-12',' ' )` this

Comment: Try it again with answer query .

Comment: i have tried it bro and i got the error invalid ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: " "

Answer (score -2):

Use MySql insert query as below to solve your problems.

```
INSERT INTO cpmu_phy_achivement
set implementor='0', scheme_code='AGR3-17', phycomp_code='3', month_code='6', finmonthcode='6', 
year_code='2017', target_ach='0', updated_by='13', remarks='', ason='2017-07-12', reason_code='';
```